# error in my code help please python

Tags: python, error-handling

here is my code it continually comes up with the same error code and im not sure why i get the error or how it relates to my code any information would help! i just am not very good at working with errors

```
import urllib.request
import codecs
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot
import copy
from time import gmtime, strftime
from urllib.request import urlopen
def readInfo(filename):
    myFile = open(filename,'r')
    data=myFile.readlines()
    namelist=[i.split(' ', 1)[0] for i in data]
    balance = list()
    for item in data:
        name = item.split()[0]
        amount = float(item.split()[1])
        balance.append([name, amount])
    print("n",namelist,"c",balance)

    return (namelist, balance)
def fetch(url):
    def find_element(line, s_pattern, e_pattern, position=0):
        shift = len(s_pattern)
        start = line.find(s_pattern, position) + shift
        position = start
        end = line.find(e_pattern, position)
        return (line[start:end], position)
    html = urlopen(url)
    records = []
    i = 0
    for line in html.readlines():
        line = line.decode()
        if "<tr><td>" not in line:
             continue  # skip if line don't contain rows
        if "Currency" in line:
            continue  # skip header

        start = "<tr><td>"
        end = "</td>"
        element, start_pos = find_element(line, start, end)
        records.append([element])
        start = "<td>"
        values = []
        for x in range(2):
            element, start_pos = find_element(line, start, end, start_pos)
            values.append(element)
        records[i].append(values)
        i = i + 1
    print(records)
    return(records)

def findCurrencyValue(records, currency_name):
    d = dict(records)
    print(d[currency_name])
    return(d[currency_name])

def transaction(filename, namelist, orgBalance, url):
    exchange_info= fetch(url)
    #Read each line from transactions.txt
    myFile = open(filename,'r')
    data=myFile.readlines()
    #Check which company is conducting transactions
    bank = dict(orgBalance)
    for line in data:
        company,action,currency,ammount = line.split()
        do_something(company,action,currency,ammount,bank)
    #If BUY, then convert the amount of foreign currency to USD
    #and subtract the calculated amount
    def find_currency_rate(currency):
    # locate the curency name in the text body and find the last <td></td> value in that row...
        return float(last_td_cell_of_row)

    def convert_to_usd(currency,amount):
        currency_rate = find_currency_rate(currency)
        return amount*currency_rate

    def do_something(company_name,action,currency_code,amount,bank):
        amount_in_usd = convert_to_usd(currency_code,amount)
        if action == "BUY":
            bank[company_name] = bank[company_name] - amount_in_usd
        else: # else we sell and add the funds to our bank
            bank[company_name] = bank[company_name] + amount_in_usd
def main():
    #get the namelist and original balance for all companies
    filename1 = "balance.txt"
    namelist, orgBalance = readInfo(filename1)
    #specifies the URL
    url = "https://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/jind/exchangerate.html"
    #calculate the current balance for all companies
    balance = copy.deepcopy(orgBalance)
    filename2 = "transactions.txt"
    curBalance = transaction(filename2, namelist, balance, url)
    #output the value for the original balance for each company
    #this output should be a list of lists
    print("Original Balance of each company is: ", orgBalance)
    #output the value for the current balance for each company
    #this output should be a list of lists
    print("Current Balance of each company is: ", curBalance)
    #call your bar graph plotting function
    plotBarGraph(orgBalance, curBalance)
    #call your pie graph plotting function
    plotPieChart(curBalance)    
main()
```

when i run the code i get the following error which i need help fixing

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\noahd\Desktop\project3\project3-skeleton.py", line 134, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\noahd\Desktop\project3\project3-skeleton.py", line 123, in main
    curBalance = transaction(filename2, namelist, balance, url)
  File "C:\Users\noahd\Desktop\project3\project3-skeleton.py", line 63, in      transaction
    company,action,currency,ammount = line.split()
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 4)
```

Comment: The error is pretty clearly telling you to look at your `line` variable, because it doesn't have exactly 4 things in it when split.  Print it out and see what's there.

Comment: Use a debugger like [pycharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/) to step through your code, or run in the debugger and it should automatically break when the exception is raised

Comment: i know where the error is, im just trying to see if someone could help me track this error to the actual problem, and if anyone can help me fix it

Comment: The problem is that your actual input doesn't match your expected inputs.  So change your inputs, or change your expectations, or somehow deal with inputs that violate your expectations.  You will likely have to do more than just one of those three.

Comment: Also, it's _really_ hard to help you with an input-based problem when you haven't shown us the input.

Comment: The title of this question could be more helpful.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that when you perform line.split(), it returns more elements than needed, should be only 4: company,action,currency,ammount.
Nevertheless, you can try:

```
try:
    company,action,currency,ammount = line.split()
except:
    print "DEBUG: split:",line.split()
```

and check where is the error

Comment: where do i put this in the code in order to run it

Comment: @NoahDukehart  You claimed above that you already knew where the error was.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
transaction,company,action,currency,ammount,_ = line.split()
```